# .net phantomjs + selenium unable to get element

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, phantomjs

All is working well when I was using Selenium alone, but when i tried with phantomjs i get null in finding elements.

```
        static void Main()
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://sellercentral.amazon.de/gp/homepage.html");
        var username = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
        var password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
        username.SendKeys("*************************");
        password.SendKeys("*************");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("sign-in-button")).Submit();
        string messagesURL = "https://sellercentral.amazon.de/gp/communication-manager/inbox.html/ref=ag_cmin__cmin?ie=UTF8&clcmResponseTimeSuboptions=&dateExactEnd=&dateExactStart=&dateFilter=&itemsPerPage=20&marketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9&otherPartyId=&pageNum=1&refIndex=40&searchBoxText=&showFilters=0&sortBy=ArrivalDate&sortOrder=Descending";
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(messagesURL);
        ParseMessages(driver);

    }

    public static void ParseMessages(IWebDriver driver) {
        var node = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("list-row-white"));
        foreach (var n in node) {
            var refNo = n.FindElement(By.ClassName("data-display-field-border-lbr"));
            Console.WriteLine(mi.refNo);

        }
    }
```

In this line of code, i get null: `var node = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("list-row-white"));`
But when i used selenium alone with actual browser, all is working. But i wanted to get things to be headless.

I am new to phantomJS, correct me if i implemented it correctly and if my code is right.

Comment: Well you don't get `null`. You'll get an empty collection if `.FindElements` doesn't find anything. Have you checked the URL & page source just before that line? I am unsure if amazon is the best site to use with a headless browser. After all, it's a very JavaScript heavy site.

Comment: Your right, as i look to the pageSource, there is no classname "list-row-white". Is there a way to enable all pageSource to load? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, PhantomJS has issues working with css related stuff or element classes.
In such case, converting locator to XPath may solve the problem.

```
// Thread.Sleep(3000) // Please, replace me with WebDriverWait ^_^ 
var node = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'list-row-white')]"));
```

Another point, PhantomJS works much faster than any other browser.
Try to insert Thread.Sleep before the failed code line.

If the code will pass -- please, replace it with proper WebDriverWait expression

Comment: I tried XPath, Thread.Sleep and WebDriverWait but no luck. Thanks anyway. Is there a way for PhantomJS to load scripts? As i look to the pagesource the element i am looking is not there.

Comment: Wylan, could you please perform one more try?
Please, set the browser window resolution to 1024x768 or larger right after the page was loaded. Sometimes, PhantomJS has an issue with small browser window sizes. 
=====================

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://sellercentral.amazon.de/gp/homepage.html");

driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);

Comment: Thanks @DmytroZharii this was the case for me with django, selenium, phantomjs and the firefox webdriver (didn't try with other webdrivers). A call to self.selenium.maximize_window() right after the page is loaded did the trick.